# Array Pointer Content Issue in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I posted a question earlier that was ill received and received some great suggestions but I was too unclear for people to help.Below is not my exact code but the premise of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<?php
$ExampleArray = [1,2,3,4];
$pointer = 0;
?>
```

I then have some HTML content:

```
<!-- Main Content -->
    <div class="large-8 large-centered columns" role="content">
        <br></br>
        <?php   
              if($example array[$pointer] === 1) 
                include 'includes/form.php';

              else
                include 'includes/buttons.php;
        ?> 
    </div>

    <div class = "small-2 columns left">
      <a href="#" class="button radius tiny"><font color = "white">Next Item</font></a>
    </div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is a way of incrementing the $pointer variable on the press of the button -> so the next item is run against the if/else check. preferably I don't want the page to refresh - but I am willing to take any suggestions.

Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: <br></br> is invalid.

Comment: What should happen when you reach the end of your array?

Comment: in reality - I have created an array of questions to be displayed - when the end of the array is reached I want to display a submit button to end the test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually done by sending `GET` or `POST`-variables.

You can for example do it like this:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['page']) or $_GET['page'] == 1) {
    $next = 2;
    include 'includes/form.php';
} else {
    $next = 3;
    include 'includes/buttons.php;
}
?>
```

And change the link to something like this:

```
<a href="scriptname.php?page=<?php echo $next; ?>" class="button radius tiny"><font color = "white">Next Item</font></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to increment that pointer value with and ajax call to a php function like

```
//in php
function incrementpointer()
{
pointer++;
}
//in javascript
$('#idofbutton').on('click',function(){
$.post( "link to that php", function( data ) {
        },);//its a general script,you dont need data here
});
```

That `$pointer` must be a global variable in that php file to be incremented. Also you can think about making it static if you want.

Comment: Many thanks - sorry to be a pain but could you point me in the right direction of an AJAX call, many thanks for the suggestion also :)